# How to deal with safeAreaView + React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, iphone-x

[image]

First screenshot was without applying `SafeAreaView` and second screenshot is applying `SafeAreaView`

[image]

As shown clearly that `Stack header` seems bulky as compare to previously. Is there anyway where we can apply `SafeAreaView` to only bottom part?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `SafeAreaView` from `React-Native`, use `SafeAreaView` from `react-navigation` as below:

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
```

Then you can use prop `forceInset` to customize the padding, which in your case,

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea} forceInset={{ top: 'never' }}>
```

For more information, [check out the iPhone X support by react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html#hidden-custom-navigation-bar-or-tab-bar)

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706007/top-bottom-black-borders-are-surrounding-the-react-native-app-in-iphone-11-sim

Answer (score 26):

For React Navigation v5, there is no `SafeAreaView` exported. The recommended way is to use [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context).

Read more: [React Navigation v5.x - Supporting safe areas](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/).

Example

```js
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function Demo() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}
    >
      <Text>This is top text.</Text>
      <Text>This is bottom text.</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>{/*(...) */}</NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the current one is out-dated

Comment: So does this mean that every screen would have to use SafeAreaView in addition to SafeAreaProvider wrapping App?

Comment: @DavidJones try it in your root component

Comment: ```<SafeAreaProvider>
   <NavigationContainer>
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
     <RootNavigator />
    </SafeAreaView>
   </NavigationContainer>
  </SafeAreaProvider> ```                                                                                   Wrapping like this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore bulky padding at the top of safeAreaView, pass edges props to control padding.

```js
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container} edges={['top', 'left', 'right']}>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>This is top text.</Text>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>This is bottom text.</Text>
</SafeAreaView>
```

[read more about it here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/)

Answer (score 0):

react-native also has  "SafeAreaView" but this works only in ios.

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
```

so set the SetAreaView with android, you use StatusBar which works only in android and its currentHeight is 24.

```
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
    <View style={{ padding: 16, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
      <Text>Page content</Text>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```