# Should I always use safeAreaView in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, safeareaview

I know that I always need to use `<safeAreaView>` to keep my content in the correct place of the screen in iOS.

Even I'm build an app just for Android, *seems* there isn't problem use `<safeAreaView>`, in case of I want to build the same app for the iOS platform.

My question is, am I wrong if I ALWAYS use `<safeAreaView>` to wrap all my content? Why would I use `<View>` if perhaps in the future I'll have to replace everything with `<safeAreaView>`?

Comment: Because you might want your content to go to the edges of the screen sometimes, underneath any notches or gesture controls.

Comment: For tabbed views, it is handled by default. For iOS with no enclosing tabs, we should use it unless as specified on answer by @Jon. As you apps scrollable area might collide with "swipe up to go to home" behavior on  iOS device with notches.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using navigation libraries like [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) or [react-native-router-flux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux) then you don't need to use `<SafeAreaView>`. These libraries manage automatically it. You have to only use when any screen has `headerMode:none` or it out side of the navigation. If you are using full screen modal then you should use `<SafeAreaView>`.

Comment: I don't thing having navigation handles it. For android it might but for iOS with swipe gesture to go to home on bottom, one must use safeareview.

Comment: React navigation doesn't handle it, but does have its own version on SafeAreaView which stops animation judders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476125/how-to-deal-with-safeareaview-react-navigation